# meaning of "a disregard for the truth and a lack of application"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the meaning of "a disregard for the truth and a lack of application" in the following paragraph?

From The Economist's [The Tories’ problems go deeper than just one man](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2022/02/19/the-tories-problems-go-deeper-than-just-one-man):

> The past few months have been torrid for the prime minister. First he
> tried a dirty parliamentary manoeuvre to protect Owen Paterson, an old
> friend and fellow MP, from punishment for his breaches of lobbying
> rules. Mr Johnson was then revealed to have attended a series of
> parties during covid-19 lockdowns. Police are now investigating; on
> February 11th his office confirmed that he was among those required to
> respond to official questioning. Tory MPs are struggling to muster the
> courage to call a vote of no confidence. They should: **a disregard
> for the truth and a lack of application** make Mr Johnson a poor prime
> minister. But he is a symptom of what ails the Conservative Party, not
> the cause. If Britain is to have the government it needs, getting rid
> of him will not be enough.

Comment: Hello Shawn, and welcome to ELL! This question, as it stands, is off-topic for this site because it's not clear enough what you're confused by. Do you understand all the words in that phrase? Have you checked for other meanings in a dictionary? Are you unsure why the article "a" is there? Are you unsure how this phrase can act as the subject for the rest of the clause? Please use the small "Edit" button below your question to make it clear what you don't understand, and someone will be glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [disregard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disregard) means a neglect. They are saying he considers the truth as unworthy of notice: it is not worth considering.

A lack of [application](https://www.lexico.com/definition/application) means a lack of sustained effort. He doesn't [apply himself](https://www.lexico.com/definition/apply) (definition 4).

In the vernacular, he lies and he's lazy.